# What is this formula doing

Tags: python, algorithm

Taken from the internet based on a JavaScript solution I found, I converted to python for the following question...

Find the nth digit of the infinite integer sequence 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, ...

The solution works which is great and I went as far as trying to figure out what length I'm in. For instance `1` digit or `2` digits or `3` digits, and so on...

I don't know how the rest of the code works though. How is it that when we subtract from our original number `n` given as input and we do

`start += (n - 1) // length`

gives us the number we should be at. I am not sure of the math here. If someone can please explain this I would be very grateful.

Another issue, perhaps being that I don't understand that first part I mentioned is what is the logic in finding the digit of the current number we should be at.

I see that

```
s = str(start)
return int(s[(n - 1) % length]);
```

but I don't know how we derive to this formula.

```
class Solution:
    def findNthDigit(self, n: int) -> int:
        length = 1;
        count = 9;
        start = 1;

        while (n > length * count):
          n -= length * count;
          length += 1;
          count *= 10;
          start *= 10;
        
        start += (n - 1) // length

        s = str(start)
        return int(s[(n - 1) % length]);
        

def main():
  x = Solution()
  print(x.findNthDigit(11))

main()
```

If we were to take any number between the range 10 - 191 and find the halfway point of that range we end up with the number we should be looking at (NOT THE DIGIT BUT THE NUMBER). How did I come up with this...

If we look at 10 and the input was 11 we know that 10 belongs to 10 and 11 belongs to 10. However, the input 10 will give us the first digit of and the input 11 will give us the second digit of 10. We know that for every number after that 11, 12, and so on there are always 2 nth inputs that will belong to it. For example the input 12 and 13 pertains both to the number 11. This is the part in the algorithm with the correct code where `start += (n - 1) // length`

I came up with this conclusion though by knowing that for any number with 2 digits will have 2 possible inputs pertaining to them.

The numbers 188 and 189 as inputs pertain to 99. 188 to the first digit and 189 to the second digit. Same logic but instead of doing what the code online does to come up with this conclusion I did

```
10 + (input - 10) // 2)
```

I kept dividing by 2 because from what I believed if we are still only looking at a number that ends up pertaining to a 2 digit number in length then it seemed appropriate.

If I were to have done this problem where there was a limit to the input, where the input could only be from 1 to 189 then any number 1 to 9 just return that number of course and for any number 10 to 189 just do

```
(10 + (input - 10) // 2)
```

and if the number given as input is even then only take the first digit and if the number given was odd then take the second digit.

This does not work for this problem though because it is infinite and any input above 189 starts to pertain to 3 digit numbers or more. I got stuck on trying to figure out the solution any further.

I'm not sure If I explained this correctly but I think it matters to say how someone came up with the conclusion. Maybe I am missing something very obvious.

Comment: What is this supposed to be doing?

Comment: There are no data structures in this code, why did you use that tag?

Comment: Is it this LeetCode problem? https://leetcode.com/problems/nth-digit/

Comment: Well I found it somewhere else and I used that tag by mistake. I'll get rid of it now. It is that leetcode problem though

Comment: The basic idea of this is that the first 9 numbers each have 1 digit, the next 90 have 2 digits, the next 900 have 3 digits, and so on. The while loop figures out which group we're in and subtracts the appropriate number of digits for the beginning of the group. The rest figures out the number and digit for the remainder within the group.

Comment: Try using a debugger and learning what it does yourself.

Comment: I know that, that is what it is doing. What I don't get is how to end up with the conclusion that `start += (n-1) // length` gives us the number to look at and the rest to give us the digit we need. I will update my question to include how someone can come to some conclusion.

Comment: I did use a debugger

Answer (score 0):

The `while` loop figures out whether the Nth digit is in the range of numbers with 1 digit, 2 digits, 3 digits, etc. At the end of the loop, `length` will be the number of digits, `start` will be the first number in the range, and `n` will have been reduced by the total number digits in the previous ranges.

For instance, in `findNthDigit(1000)`, after the loop we get `n = 811, length = 3, start = 100`. So the 1000th digit is the 811th digit in the range `100-999`.

`(n - 1) // length` then determines how far into the range we have to go to find the number containing the nth digit. We subtract 1 because this calculation should be 0-based, but `n` is 1-based. Then we divide by the number of digits in each number. `810 // 3` means that this is `270` numbers into the range.

We add this to `start` to get the actual number in the range at that position. So the digit we want is in `370`.

Finally, we use the remainder of the above division to determine which digit to return. `(n - 1) % length` is that remainder. In this case, the remainder is `0`, so we return the first digit. We convert the number `370` to a string, and use that remainder as the index into the string. We extract it, convert it back to a number with `int()`, and return it.

Comment: Thanks. I understand most of what you said but what does it mean by subtract 1 because this calculation is 0-based, but n is 1-based

Comment: Oh actually I think what you're saying is if we start from 10 that is 0 based were not starting from 11 and same as 100 and not 101 and so forth correct?

Comment: Suppose n = 3, start = 100, length = 3. The answer should be the 3rd digit of 100. But 3/3 would be 1, and when we add that to start we would get 101. We want our indexing to start from 0, not 1.

Comment: Yes, you got it.